Is it possible to use a modified version of a class template parameter pack in a members template?
I am trying to write a class template with a variadic template parameter pack which is separated into two groups of arguments. Those shall be used in member templates.
template <class... Args>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const Args&... args) :gr1{/*...*/}, gr2{/*...*/} {} 
private:
    template_one<Group1...> gr1;
    template_two<Group2...> gr2;
};

What I have come up with is:
A type sorter which returns a pair of tuples containing sorted types.
template <typename... Args>
struct type_sorter;

template <>
struct type_sorter<> {
    constexpr static auto sort() {return std::pair<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>>{}; }
};

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct type_sorter<Arg, Args...> {
    constexpr static auto sort() {
        auto ret = type_sorter<Args...>::sort();

        if constexpr (std::is_function_v<Arg>)
            return std::make_pair(std::tuple_cat(ret.first, std::tuple<Arg*>{}), ret.second);
        else
            return std::make_pair(ret.first, std::tuple_cat(ret.second, std::tuple<Arg>{}));
    }
};

A param sorter which returns a pair of tuples containing both sorted types and parameters.
template <class Arg>
constexpr auto param_sort(Arg&& arg) {
    if constexpr (std::is_function_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>)
        return std::make_pair(std::tuple<Arg>(arg), std::tuple<>());
    else
        return std::make_pair(std::tuple<>(), std::tuple<Arg>(arg));
}

template <class Arg, class... Args>
constexpr auto param_sort(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args) {
    auto ret = param_sort(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    if constexpr (std::is_function_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>)
        return std::make_pair(std::tuple_cat(ret.first, std::tuple<Arg>(arg)), ret.second);
    else
        return std::make_pair(ret.first, std::tuple_cat(ret.second, std::tuple<Arg>(arg)));
}

Currently std::is_function is the sorting criterion.
The former can be used to sort types without having to provide arguments while the later sorts both the template parameters and the arguments. This is useful when having only access to the template parameter pack. (At class scope.)
Now they both return tuples:
I would like to be able to extract the parameter packs (Group1, Group2) from the tuples generated by type sorter and use it in the declaration of template_one and template_two.
What I tried is:
template_one<decltype(std::get<
  std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<
    decltype(type_sorter<Inputs...>::sort().second)
  >>>(type_sorter<Inputs...>::sort().second)...)
> gr1 {};

Doesn't compile.
Is something like that even possible?

please explain in terms of an example, how Args&... args should be split into two groups. You are immediately jumping to some implementation that is difficult to understand before it is clear what their purpose is

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Implementation works and has been tested on a separate test bench. It isn't the core of the problem.
Anyways, here is how it works:
In both cases recursion is used to determine for each type of the parameter pack to which tuple of a pair it should belong.
A tuple containing that type is then concatenated with the respective tuple and returned. (See inside the if constexpr).

Why not use template <typename Tuple1, typename Tuple2> class Foo; and template <typename...Ts1, typename... Ts2> class Foo<std::tuple<Ts1..., Ts2...>>{};?

I am not saying that there is something wrong with the implementation. Its just difficult to understand, because it is not obvious what it supposed to be good for. Only after reading the question back and forth several times I understand what you are doing. A concrete example would help to understand. Moreover "Doesnt work" is better illustrated by means of a [mcve] that others can compile to see the errors

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Alright, I will add the details requested, as soon as I am able to.

It seems you want something like template <template <typename...> class Template, typename Tuple> Substitute { using type = ???; }; that would take tuple<A, B, C> and produce Template<A. B. C>. This is reasonably easy to arrange.

I am not requesting but suggesting. The difference is subtle but important ;). It is difficult to know what is actually needed from the pov of someone not completely understanding the question

Question can indeed be improved, 463035818_is_not_an_ai and I understand the issue differently, so 2 answers resolving different issues... Both might help you though :-)

For me question is focus to much on explaining how you are trying to achieve something, instead explain what kind of problem this template should solve. What should this param_sort actually do?

@Jarod42 I didn't know that partial template specialization allows for using multiple variadic template parameter packs on class/constructor. Retrospectively your approach would be simpler while achieving something similar. It would however require me to use tuples when initializing my object. Now that I dove into that topic, just for the sake of science/exercise, I want to implement a class template, that accepts arguments of a given set of types in a arbitrary order, and is able to initialize the correct fields after sorting those arguments based on their types.

"It would however require me to use tuples when initializing my object" Not necessary, "flatten" elements would be OK too(so instead of Foo(std::tuple<Ts1...>t1, std::tuple<Ts2...>t2)use Foo(Ts1...t1, Ts2...t2) constructor is not template Ts1/Ts2 are fixed from the class), but CTAD would be problematic then. But for reordering, intermediate packing struct (as tuple) seems required.

If i correctly understand the question you are looking for a way to get foo<A...> given some std::tuple<A...>.
You can write a trait for that :
template <template <typename ...> class T,typename A> 
struct tuple_expander;

template <template <typename ...> class T,typename ...B>
struct tuple_expander<T,std::tuple<B...>> {
    using type = T<B...>;
};

Live Demo

With Delegating constructor, you might do:
template <class... Args>
class Foo {
    using Tuple1 = decltype(type_sorter<Args...>::sort())::first_type;
    using Tuple2 = decltype(type_sorter<Args...>::sort())::second_type;

    Foo(const std::pair<Tuple1, Tuple2>& p) :gr1{p.first}, gr2{p.second} {}

public:
    Foo(const Args&... args) : Foo(param_sort(args...)) {}

private:
    Tuple1 gr1;
    Tuple2 gr2;
};

Demo
